# Concat parameters from object list

Tags: java, string, list, java-stream

I have list of objects:

```
List<Obj> objList = [obj1, obj2]

obj1.val = "val1"
obj2.val = "val2"
```

And I want to concat String parameters from that objects with "." separator.
I tried to concatenate them with stream :

```
objList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("."));
```

But I can't figure it out how to concat only parameters from objects.

In this case the result should be "val1.val2"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to concatenate them with stream  objList.stream()..collect(Collectors.joining("."));  but I can figure it out how to concat only parameters from objects.

Comment: Then update the question adding what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the map operator here. You have to add map operator to the stream processing pipeline before collecting it. Here's how it looks.

```
objList.stream().map(Obj::val).collect(Collectors.joining("."));
```